# Google Protocol Buffer based socket cclient

Tags: c++, sockets, protocol-buffers

I have written a c++ code using google protocol buffer, but while running  it is showing error "not declared in this scope", almost at each line.I have also included the required headers,I think I am missing one of the steps, please help. Here is the code..

```
---------socket1.proto-------
  message socket_packet {
  required int32 d_size=1;
  required string data=2;
   }
----------protocolclient.cpp-----
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "socket1.pb.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <google/protobuf/message.h>
#include <google/protobuf/descriptor.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.h>

std::streampos fileSize( const char* filePath ){

    std::streampos fsize = 0;
    std::ifstream file( filePath, std::ios::binary );

    fsize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );
    fsize = file.tellg() - fsize;
    file.close();

    return fsize;
}
using namespace google::protobuf::io;

using namespace std;
int main(int argv, char** argc){

    /* Coded output stream */

    socket_packet payload ;
    int bytes_read;
    std::streampos a1;
    a1=filesize("test.txt");
    payload.set_d_size(a1);
    char *temp=new char[a1];
    FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    bytes_read=fread(temp,sizeof(char),600000,f);
    fclose(f);
    payload.set_data(temp);
    delete temp;

    cout<<"size after serilizing is "<<payload.ByteSize()<<endl;
    int siz = payload.ByteSize()+4;
    char *pkt = new char [siz];
    google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream aos(pkt,siz);
    CodedOutputStream *coded_output = new CodedOutputStream(&aos);
    coded_output->WriteVarint32(payload.ByteSize());
    payload.SerializeToCodedStream(coded_output);

        int host_port= 1101;
        char* host_name="127.0.0.1";

        struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

        char buffer[1024];
        int bytecount;
        int buffer_len=0;

        int hsock;
        int * p_int;
        int err;

        hsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(hsock == -1){
                printf("Error initializing socket %d\n",errno);
                goto FINISH;
        }

        p_int = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *p_int = 1;

        if( (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1 )||
                (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1 ) ){
                printf("Error setting options %d\n",errno);
                free(p_int);
                goto FINISH;
        }
        free(p_int);

        my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
        my_addr.sin_port = htons(host_port);

        memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
        my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_name);
        if( connect( hsock, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == -1 ){
                if((err = errno) != EINPROGRESS){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting socket %d\n", errno);
                        goto FINISH;
                }
        }




       for (int i =0;i<10000;i++){
          for (int j = 0 ;j<10;j++) {

                if( (bytecount=send(hsock, (void *) pkt,siz,0))== -1 ) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", errno);
                        goto FINISH;
                }
                printf("Sent bytes %d\n", bytecount);
                usleep(1);
         }
        }
        delete pkt;



FINISH:
        close(hsock);

return 0;

}
------------errors---------------
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x19d): undefined reference to `socket_packet::socket_packet()'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x289): undefined reference to `socket_packet::ByteSize() const'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x2c0): undefined reference to `socket_packet::ByteSize() const'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x301): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream::ArrayOutputStream(void*, int, int)'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x320): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::CodedOutputStream(google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream*)'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x336): undefined reference to `socket_packet::ByteSize() const'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x349): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteVarint32(unsigned int)'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x362): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::MessageLite::SerializeToCodedStream(google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*) const'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x60a): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream::~ArrayOutputStream()'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x619): undefined reference to `socket_packet::~socket_packet()'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x64e): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::ArrayOutputStream::~ArrayOutputStream()'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x662): undefined reference to `socket_packet::~socket_packet()'
/tmp/ccO6KTWG.o: In function `socket_packet::set_data(char const*)':
protocolclient.cpp:(.text._ZN13socket_packet8set_dataEPKc[_ZN13socket_packet8set_dataEPKc]+0x29): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::kEmptyString'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
--------------protocolserver.cpp-----------------
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "socket1.pb.h"
#include<fstream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace google::protobuf::io;



void* SocketHandler(void*);


int main(int argv, char** argc)
{

        int host_port= 1101;

        struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

        int hsock;
        int * p_int ;
        int err;

        socklen_t addr_size = 0;
        int* csock;
        sockaddr_in sadr;
        pthread_t thread_id=0;

        hsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(hsock == -1){
                printf("Error initializing socket %d\n", errno);
                goto FINISH;
        }

        p_int = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *p_int = 1;

        if( (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1 )||
                (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1 ) ){
                printf("Error setting options %d\n", errno);
                free(p_int);
                goto FINISH;
        }
        free(p_int);

        my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
        my_addr.sin_port = htons(host_port);

        memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
        my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY ;

        if( bind( hsock, (sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == -1 ){
                fprintf(stderr,"Error binding to socket, make sure nothing else is listening on this port %d\n",errno);
                goto FINISH;
        }
        if(listen( hsock, 10) == -1 ){
                fprintf(stderr, "Error listening %d\n",errno);
                goto FINISH;
        }

        //Now lets do the server stuff

        addr_size = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

        while(true){
                printf("waiting for a connection\n");
                csock = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
                if((*csock = accept( hsock, (sockaddr*)&sadr, &addr_size))!= -1){
                        printf("---------------------\nReceived connection from %s\n",inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr));
                        pthread_create(&thread_id,0,&SocketHandler, (void*)csock );
                        pthread_detach(thread_id);
                }
                else{
                        fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting %d\n", errno);
                }
        }



FINISH:
        free(csock);
return 0;
}


google::protobuf::uint32 readHdr(char *buf)
{
  google::protobuf::uint32 size;
  google::protobuf::io::ArrayInputStream ais(buf,4);
  CodedInputStream coded_input(&ais);
  coded_input.ReadVarint32(&size);//Decode the HDR and get the size
  cout<<"size of payload is "<<size<<endl;
  return size;
}

void readBody(int csock,google::protobuf::uint32 siz)
{
  int bytecount;
  socket_packet payload;
  char buffer [siz+4];//size of the payload and hdr
  //Read the entire buffer including the hdr
  if((bytecount = recv(csock, (void *)buffer, 4+siz, MSG_WAITALL))== -1){
                fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d\n", errno);
        }
  cout<<"Second read byte count is "<<bytecount<<endl;
  //Assign ArrayInputStream with enough memory 
  google::protobuf::io::ArrayInputStream ais(buffer,siz+4);
  CodedInputStream coded_input(&ais);
  //Read an unsigned integer with Varint encoding, truncating to 32 bits.
  coded_input.ReadVarint32(&siz);
  //After the message's length is read, PushLimit() is used to prevent the CodedInputStream 
  //from reading beyond that length.Limits are used when parsing length-delimited 
  //embedded messages
  google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::Limit msgLimit = coded_input.PushLimit(siz);
  //De-Serialize
  payload.ParseFromCodedStream(&coded_input);
  //Once the embedded message has been parsed, PopLimit() is called to undo the limit
  coded_input.PopLimit(msgLimit);
  //Print the message
  cout<<"Message is "<<payload.DebugString();

}

void* SocketHandler(void* lp){
    int *csock = (int*)lp;

        char buffer[4];
        int bytecount=0;
        string output,pl;
        socket_packet logp;

        memset(buffer, '\0', 4);

        while (1) {
        //Peek into the socket and get the packet size
        if((bytecount = recv(*csock,
                         buffer,
                                 4, MSG_PEEK))== -1){
                fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d\n", errno);
        }else if (bytecount == 0)
                break;
        cout<<"First read byte count is "<<bytecount<<endl;
        readBody(*csock,readHdr(buffer));
        }
}
-----error----
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccQmwjxg.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Could you please provided more detailed info about compilation ? What do you compile it with ? Which options do you use ?

Comment: I have installed protobuff compiler , using sudo apt-get install protobuf compiler and created the socket1.pb.h and socket1.pb.cc. I have downloaded  protobuf master package and kept it in the same folder. Now when I am doing g++ protocolclient.cpp it is showing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to link protobuf libraries. Try adding protobuf library path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and compiling the code using:

`g++ protocolclient.cpp socket1.pb.cc -lprotobuf -lpthread -o protoclient`

Or you can just specify library search path while building:

`g++ protocolclient.cpp socket1.pb.cc -L/path/to/protobuf -lprotobuf -lpthread -o protoclient`

Comment: Can you please tell me How to add protobuf library path to LD_LLIBRARY_PATH....Should I give the path to the Protobuff master folder....Please help..

Comment: First, check isn't it already there - it might be if you installed it via apt-get, so just run the compilation as described. If it is not use  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/protobuf/library:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Hey I had done both ways...it is not working...it is giving these errors..

Comment: protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x1b1): undefined reference to `socket_packet::socket_packet()'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x29d): undefined reference to `socket_packet::ByteSize() const'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `socket_packet::ByteSize() const'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x34a): undefined reference to `socket_packet::ByteSize() const'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x62d): undefined reference to `socket_packet::~socket_packet()'
protocolclient.cpp:(.text+0x676): undefined reference to `socket_packet::~socket_packet()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Thank you......it solved the problem....but now I am facing a single problem with protocolserver.cpp.....I am attaching the file and the code....please help if posiible.

Comment: @Rimita, so could you please mark my answer as solution ?